# How do I run Anaconda through Bash application on Windows?

Tags: windows, anaconda, git-shell

I installed Anaconda on Windows via the normal setup.
The normal setup (to me) lets me run Anaconda from Windows' Command Prompt.

Since I'm used to Linux, I tried using Anaconda from Bash Shell (on Windows as well).  And I also found a way to install it on Bash from the beginning [on this link](https://www.cgranade.com/blog/2016/08/22/qutip-on-wsl.html).

I'd like to just use the current installation, instead of having to reinstall everything.  Is that possible?

Comment: Was there an error while using the bash shell? Is this the Windows Subsystem for Linux or the Git-Bash shell?